# AbstractStack is a integer stack class and an abstract class

Tags: stack, abstract

```
class AbstractStack  
{  
    public :  
        virtual bool push(int n) = 0;// push n to the stack. If the stack is full, return false 
        virtual bool pop(int& n) = 0;// store the integer that popped from the stack to n,if the stack is empty return false.  
        virtual int size() = 0; //return number of integers that has been stored to the stack
}
```

Inheriting class AbstractStack, how can I create "class IntStack" where it 'pushes' and 'pops' integer?

I've so far tried

```
class IntStack : public AbstractStack{  
bool push(int n);
bool pop(int &n);

}
```

Comment: By writing some code.  What have you attempted so far?

Comment: You need to implement every method that was pure-virtual in the `AbstractStack` class in the `IntStack` implementation class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there's a few pure-virtual methods (that's what the `= 0` does) this means that any derived class must implement these methods.

`AbstractStack` defines an interface to manipulate your user-defined Stack types. This means that the code can use the same syntax to access the different types of Stack with different underlying types.

So given this:

```
class AbstractStack{  
    public :  
        virtual bool push(int n) = 0;
        virtual bool pop(int& n) = 0;
        virtual int size() = 0;
};
```

You would want to do something like this:

```
class IntStack: public AbstractStack{  
    public:  
        bool push(int n){
            //implement the push() for Ints here
        }
        bool pop(int& n){
            //implement the pop() for Ints here
        }
        int size(){
            //implement the size() for Ints here
        }
    private:
        //Here you need to specify the underlying storage type that this class uses
        //to store the stack of int's
        stack_t m_stack;
}; //Don't forget the trailing ;!
```